# Laravel 5.5 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

i've copied my Laravel project (from windows to centos7) to server but when i trying to acces it form browser i got **vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233**

the server actually running php 7.1

```
php -v

PHP 7.1.11 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2017 17:26:51) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.11, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies



 yum list installed | grep -i php

mod_php71w.x86_64                      7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-bcmath.x86_64                   7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-cli.x86_64                      7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-common.x86_64                   7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-dba.x86_64                      7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-devel.x86_64                    7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-embedded.x86_64                 7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-fpm.x86_64                      7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-gd.x86_64                       7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-imap.x86_64                     7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-interbase.x86_64                7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-intl.x86_64                     7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-ldap.x86_64                     7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-mbstring.x86_64                 7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-mcrypt.x86_64                   7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-mysql.x86_64                    7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-odbc.x86_64                     7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-opcache.x86_64                  7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-pdo.x86_64                      7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-pdo_dblib.x86_64                7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-pear.noarch                     1:1.10.4-1.w7                   @webtatic

php71w-process.x86_64                  7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-pspell.x86_64                   7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-recode.x86_64                   7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-tidy.x86_64                     7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-xml.x86_64                      7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic

php71w-xmlrpc.x86_64                   7.1.11-1.w7                     @webtatic
```

i've been trying to downgrade to php 7.0 but still got the error

Comment: and what is the actual error, not just what you thought was relevant

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /opt/lampp/laravel-framework/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233

Comment: your webserver is not running PHP 7 ... on that line in that file is a new feature from PHP 7 `??`

Comment: Note that it's possible to be running PHP 7 via the cli and PHP 5 via web. You should confirm what version of PHP your webserver is using.

Comment: thank you so much i just notice that, in web the version is 5.6,, i;m using xampp by the way. I've trying to install xampp-v7 and restart the server.. everything works fine know :D thank you